# advisable vs advised

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I recently found myself reading a phase with one of the terms. It sounded wrong.

Which one is correct/better?

1) Regardless, it is **advisable** to follow X guidelines
2) Regardless, it is **advised** to follow X guidelines

I did some searching on the matter, but couldn't come up with anything solid.

Comment: Which one was it you read, and why did it sound wrong to you?

Comment: The first one sounded... off. I can't give a good reason for it. It just did. Maybe because i see `advise` as "optional" rather than "a strict requirement". Also `-able` makes it even more optional. Am I overthinking it?

Comment: To be honest both of them seem off to me. "advisable" in my eyes has more of a connotation of "it's possible to advise this" rather than "we're advising it". On the other side, it seems to me that the passive voice "it is advised" should be followed by "that" so I'd word it as "Regardless, it is advised that you follow X guidelines". Or, since I prefer active sentence, "Regardless, we advise that you follow X guidelines."

Comment: I'd say the second one is less natural sounding. It is a mandative subjunctive, which doesn't usually use "to"; a more common form would be, "...it is advised [that] you follow X guidelines." I see the first as completely acceptable (advisable is not a mandative subjunctive.) "It is prudent to follow X." (Native AmE speaker here.)